# Set breakpoint on specific value of watched variable

Tags: c#, .net, breakpoints, conditional-breakpoint

I'm sure I have seen the answer to this on here before but I can't find it.

How do I, using code, set a breakpoint on a specific variable getting a specific value?

[This is not what I'm looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488155/can-i-set-a-breakpoint-when-variable-is-getting-specific-value-in-net), there is a way to do it in code too.

In case it is not supported in all .NET languages I'm looking for a C# answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached && yourVariable == specificValue)
  System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Comment: I didnt remember the exact command too, just lucky to found it.

Comment: You might also want to look on [conditional breakpoints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670415/how-to-set-conditional-breakpoints-in-visual-studio).